# How to send formData with nervgh's Angular-File-Upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using nervgh's Angular-File-Upload at
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

It is working like a charm when I hard code the `preOpKey`.  What I would like to do is to send the `preOpKey` along with the file so that I can save the file to the appropriate record in the database.

angular-file-upload has a `fileData` in the API which I'm populating in `$scope.OnPreinspectionSubmit()` but for some reason I can't find that value once `SaveFile()` in my MVC controller is called.

I just need to know how to pass a value along with my file and then access it in my MVC controller.  I guess it would be convenient to send it in the `fileData` but that isn't required to answer my question.

Here is my Angular controller:

```
var OperatorPreinspectionControllers = angular.module('OperatorPreinspectionControllers', ['angularFileUpload']);

OperatorPreinspectionControllers.controller('OperatorPreinspectionCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'FileUploader',
    function ($scope, $http, FileUploader) {

        $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: pageBaseUrl + 'image/SaveFile'
        });

        $scope.uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'imageFilter',
            fn: function (item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
                return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|pdf|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
            }
        });

        // Send the form data to the database
        $scope.OnPreinspectionSubmit = function () {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save this information?")) {
                $http.post(pageBaseUrl + 'api/PreInspectionForm', $scope.formInformation).success(function (returnData) {
                    $scope.uploader.formData.push({ preOpKey: returnData });
                    $scope.uploader.uploadAll(); // Upload file
                });
            } else { }
        }
    }
]);
```

Here is my MVC Controller:

```
public void SaveFile()
    {
        HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
        HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile = files[0];

        var preOpKey = 123; // ???????

        // Turn the file into bytes
        byte[] data;
        using(Stream inputStream = uploadedFile.InputStream)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
            if(memoryStream == null)
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            }
            data = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        PreOpManager.SaveImage(preOpKey, data, uploadedFile.FileName, uploadedFile.ContentType);
    }
```

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: I think you can just send the key via the longhand post data:$http({
    url: 'request-url',
    method: "POST",
    data: { 'message' : message }
}) then just pick up on the json post data and submit to the database.

Comment: There must be a bug in nervgh's Angular-File-Upload. I ended up pulling it out and using danialfarid's Angular-File-Upload which has a "formData" only this one works. :)

Comment: Wow, unfortunate.  Well, glad you got it all sorta.

Comment: me too using the nervgh's Angular-File-Upload and facing difficulty in passing file to .net mvc wep api controller

Answer (score 12):

The one solution that has so far worked flawlessly for me has been:

```
$scope.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = onBeforeUploadItem;

function onBeforeUploadItem(item) {
  item.formData.push({your: 'data'});
  console.log(item);
}
```

As per https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/issues/97#issuecomment-39248062